# How to correctly and safely free() all memory used a nested struct in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, linked-list, c99

I have four different layers of struct nested. The code is as follows:

```
typedef struct System system;  
typedef struct College college;
typedef struct Student student;
typedef struct Family family;

#define MAX_COLLEGES 10
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 32
#define MAX_STUDENTS 10

struct System {
    college *Colleges[MAX_COLLEGES];
};

struct College {
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    student *Students[MAX_STUDENTS];
};

struct Student {
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    int id;
    family *fam; //was typo familiy
};

struct Family {
    char fatherName[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    char motherName[MAX_NAME_LEN];
};
```

And I allocated memory to all of them (I'm not sure if I allocated all of them correctly), as follows:

```
system *collegeSys = malloc(sizeof(system));
college *colleges = malloc(sizeof(college));
student *students = malloc(sizeof(student));
family *fam = malloc(sizeof(family));

// then the following is initialization
...
...
...
```

Now, I need to delete the `collegeSys` structure and anything associated with it. So, I don't know if I can just free the first `collegeSys` struct without freeing any other structs, like this:

```
free(collegeSys);
```

Or in order to "delete anything associated with it", I have to free everything bottom-up, like this:

```
free(fam);
free(students);
free(colleges);
free(collegeSys);
```

Or to that end, I even have to free anything included inside each struct and free them bottom-up, like this:

```
free (fam -> fatherName);
free (fam -> motherName);
free (fam);
free (students -> name);
free (students -> id);
free (students -> fam);
free (students)
.
. till
.
free (collegeSys -> colleges);
free (collegeSys);
```

Which one is the correct and safe way to free the memory? Or none of them is?

Comment: Do you want 10 colleges as part of system. The current structures allocate an array of pointers of colleges, which is equivalent to a 2D array

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Yeah. 10 colleges are a part of the system, and 10 students a part of each college. So, it shouldn't be a 2D array, which means a pointer is enough (indeed, for this purpose I only need a 1D array)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand point of having array of pointers, it could be done with pointer.

**Definition:**

```
struct System {
    college *Colleges;
};

struct College {
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    student *Students;
};

struct Student {
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    int id;
    familiy *fam;
};

struct Family {
    char fatherName[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    char motherName[MAX_NAME_LEN];
};
```

**Allocation and initialization :**

```
system *collegeSys = malloc(sizeof(*collegeSys));
collegeSys->colleges = malloc(MAX_COLLEGES * sizeof(*(collegeSys->colleges)));
collegeSys->colleges->students = malloc(MAX_STUDENTS * sizeof(*(collegeSys->colleges->students)));
collegeSys->colleges->students->fam = malloc(sizeof(*(collegeSys->colleges->students->fam)));
```

**Freeing:**

```
free(collegeSys->colleges->students->fam);
free(collegeSys->colleges->students);
free(collegeSys->colleges);
free(collegeSys);
```

---

**Update:**

> Like I want to have struct student A, B, C, D under a struct college

```
 collegeSys->colleges->students[0] = A;
 collegeSys->colleges->students[1] = B;
 collegeSys->colleges->students[2] = C;
 collegeSys->colleges->students[3] = D;
```

Should do it.

If yo have array of `student`s you can use `memcpy` or copy in `loop`.

```
struct student stud[MAX_STUDENTS] = {...};

memcpy(collegeSys->colleges->students[2], stud, MAX_STUDENTS);
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i< MAX_STUDENTS; i++)
     collegeSys->colleges->students[i] = stud[i];
```

---

**Note:**

You can assign the array to `collegeSys->colleges->students` in that case you don't need dynamic memory allocation or freeing.

```
 // collegeSys->colleges->students = malloc(MAX_STUDENTS * sizeof(*(collegeSys->colleges->students)));  //Leaks memory

 collegeSys->colleges->students = stud;

//free(collegeSys->colleges->students); //wrong
```

Comment: Thank you. Though I'm unsure if I'm right, I try to store multiple student information under a college struct by an array of pointers, the same thing trying to do with colleges under a system. With just a pointer, to have multiple students information under a college also works? Like I want to have `struct student A, B, C, D` under a `struct college`.

Comment: So do I just increase the size of `MAX_STUDENTS` for allocating the memory if I want to have more of the students?

Comment: @SpittyDog Yes.

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate a structure then set all pointers in it to NULL.
For example to allocate your College structure you need to set all the students to NULL:

```
struct College* CollegeAlloc( char name[MAX_NAME_LEN] ) {
    struct College* college = malloc( sizeof(struct College) );
    if ( college ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_STUDENTS; ++i )
            college->Students[i] = NULL;
        memcpy( college->name, name, MAX_NAME_LEN );
    }
    return college;
}
```

Alternatively you could add a count field in the structures for each array, in order to count the number of array elements that are actually used.

If you set the array element to NULL when not used then you can free from the bottom up first.

```
void FamilyFree( struct Family *fam ) {
    free( fam );
}
void StudentFree( struct Student *student ) {
    if ( student ) {
        FamilyFree( student->fam );
        free( student );
    }
}
void CollegeFree( struct College *college ) {
    if ( college ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_STUDENTS; ++i )
            StudentFree( college->Students[i] );
        free( college );
    }
}
void SystemFree( struct System *sys ) {
    if ( sys ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_COLLEGES; ++i )
            CollegeFree( sys->Colleges[i] );
        free( sys );
    }
}
```

Note this assumes that there is **no sharing** of pointers, e.g. the same student being at more than one college (when the implementation has allocated just one structure for each student), or when there are two siblings who share the same family structure. (the family structure does not model families very well, e.g. single parents, divorced, remarried, gay parents, legal guardians).
When structures can be shared then you can put a reference count in the structure and free only when it is reduced to zero.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. A couple of questions:
**1) Can we use `college -> Students[i] = NULL` if we only defined a student structure pointer rather than an array of pointers inside the college structure?** e.g.
`struct College {
    ......
    struct Student *student;
}`
I think we can't do this. I tried this on Xcode, it threw an error _assigning to ... incompatible type 'void *'_.
**2) Do we have to set all pointers in it to NULL when we allocate memory to a structure?**
e.g. is it okay to only do this:
`struct system* collegeSys = malloc(sizeof(struct system));`

Comment: **3) Do we only need to NULL the substructure defined in its parent structure instead of NULLing everything nested in it if we do?** e.g. in your first code block, you only NULLed the student structure and didn't NULL the family structure nested in the student struct. So, to NULL family struct is the job we should do when we allocate memory to student struct rather than when we allocate memory to college struct, is it?

Comment: 1. No. Students needs to be of type array of struct Student* (or equivalent typedef). Alternatively type could be struct Student**, and assign a dynamic array allocated with calloc(). Then use the index [] notation.

Comment: @SpittyDog 2. If you don't initialize then the contents can be random meaningless values. If you have some other way of tracking what is initialized and what isn't then you don't have to initialize. That approach would require additional data and programming care.

Comment: @SpittyDog 3. The Student struct has not been allocated yet. So you can't do anything to the student struct. i.e it is creating the empty student places if the Students array. You would eventually want to allocate a student struct, initialize it, and put it in one of the (unused) elements of the Students array in the College struct. This would be an "Enrol" function.