# How is memory allocated to multi-nested structs in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct, memory-leaks

A couple of days ago, I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56898313/how-to-correctly-and-safely-free-all-memory-used-a-nested-struct-in-c). I duplicated 90% of the code given in the answer to my previous question. However, when I used Valgrind to do memcheck, it told me that there were memory leaks. But I don't think it was that 10% difference that caused the memory leaks. In addition to the memory leak issue, I have a couple of other questions.

A brief summary of my previous post:
I have a multi-nested struct. I need to correctly allocate memory to it and free the memory later on. The structure of the entire struct should look like this:

```
                          College Sys
           |           |           |      ...      |
        ColleA       ColleB      ColleC   ...     ColleX
    |  |  |  |    |  |  |  |   |  |  |  |  ...  |  |  |  |
   sA sB sC  sD  sA sB sC  sD sA sB sC  sD ... sA sB sC  sD
    |  |  |  |    |  |  |  |   |  |  |  |  ...  |  |  |  | 
   fam fam ...
// Colle is short for college
// s is short for stu (which is short for student)
```

There could be arbitrary number of colleges and students, which is controllable by `#define MAX_NUM _num_`.

---

As per the previous answer, I should allocate memory in the order of "outermost to innermost" and free the memory "innermost to outermost". I basically understand the logic behind the pattern. The following questions are extensions to it.

1) Does

```
CollegeSys -> Colle = malloc(sizeof(*(CollegeSys -> Colle)) * MAX_NUM);
CollegeSys -> Colle -> stu = malloc(sizeof(*(CollegeSys -> Colle -> stu)) * MAX_NUM);
CollegeSys -> Colle -> stu -> fam = malloc(sizeof(*(CollegeSys -> Colle -> stu -> fam)));
```

mean " there are `MAX_NUM` colleges under the college system, each of which has `MAX_NUM` students — each of which has one family"?

1.a)If yes, do I still need **for loops** to initialize every single value contained in this huge struct? 
For example, the possibly correct way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM; i++) {
    strcpy(CollegeSys -> Colle[i].name, "collestr");
    for (int n = 0; n < MAX_NUM; n++) {
        strcpy(system -> Colle[i].stu[n].name, "stustr");
        ...
    }
}
```

the possibly incorrect way:

```
strcpy(CollegeSys -> Colle -> name, "collestr");
strcpy(CollegeSys -> Colle -> stu -> name, "stustr");
```

I tried the "possibly incorrect way". There was no syntax error, but it would only initialize `CollegeSys -> Colle[0].name` and `... -> stu[0].name`. So, the second approach is very likely to be incorrect if I want to initialize every single attribute.

2) If I modularize this whole process, separating the process into several functions that return corresponding struct pointers — `newSystem(void)`, `newCollege(void)`, `newStudent(void)` (arguments might not necessarily be void; we might also pass a `str` as the `name` to the functions; besides, there might be a series of `addStu()`, etc... to assign those returned pointers to the corresponding part of `CollegeSys`). When I create a new CollegeSys in `newSystem()`, is it correct to malloc memory to every nested struct once and for all within `newSystem()`?

2.a) If I allocate memory to all parts of the struct in `newSystem()`, the possible consequence I can think of so far is there would be memory leaks. Since we've allocated memory to all parts when creating the system, we inevitably have to create a new struct pointer and allocate adequate memory to it in the other two functions too. For instance,

```
struct Student* newStudent(void) {
   struct Student* newStu = malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
   newStu -> fam = malloc(sizeof(*(newStu -> fam)));
   // I'm not sure if I'm supposed to also allocate memoty to fam struct
   ...
   return newStu;
}
```

If so, we actually allocate the same amount of memory to an instance at least twice — one in the `newSystem(void)`, the other in `newStudent(void)`. If I'm correct so far, this is definitely memory leak. And the memory we allocate to the pointer `newStu` in `newStudent(void)` can never be freed (I think so). Then, what is the correct way to allocate memory to the whole structure when we separate the whole memory allocation process into several small steps?

3) Do we have to use `sizeof(*(layer1 -> layer2 -> ...))` when malloc'ing memory to a struct nested in a struct? Can we directly specify the type of it? For example, doing this

```
CollegeSys -> Colle = malloc(sizeof(struct College) * MAX_NUM);
// instead of 
// CollegeSys -> Colle = malloc(sizeof(*(CollegeSys -> Colle)) * MAX_NUM);
```

4) It seems even if we allocate a certain amount of memory to a pointer, we still can't prevent segfault. For example, we code

```
// this is not completely correct C code, just to show what I mean
struct* ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct type) * 3);
```

We still could call `ptr[3]`, `ptr[4]` and so on, and the compiler will print out nonsense. Sometimes, the compiler may throw an error but sometimes may not. So, essentially, we can't rely on `malloc` (or `calloc` and so forth) to avoid the appearance of segfault?

I'm sorry about writing such a long text. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: You need to call `free` exactly as many times as you call `malloc`. It doesn't get much simpler than that.

Comment: Rule of thumb: allocate:top-to-bottom; free:bottom-to-top. And: you can create a function for every "constructor"/"destructor".

Comment: The code in the previous question shows array members, such as `college *Colleges[MAX_COLLEGES];`, inside other structures. With array members, the members are part of the enclosing structure, and allocating memory in the enclosing structure allocates memory for its members. In this question, you might have changed those array members to be pointers, but you have not shown the code for that, so we are not sure.

Comment: Overall, it looks like you are thinking about memory allocation and layout in unclear ways. If a structure contains a pointer, that pointer is uninitialized until it is given a value. If you have structures containing pointers to structures that contain pointers to structures, then certainly you must initialize each and every pointer (and each and every object of any sort) before using it.

Comment: Generally, it is bad practice to allocate a constant number of items such as students for a college. Good practice is to adapt the size as need grows. Using constants for maximum numbers of colleges or students is something early programming students do. It is tolerable for getting started and novice level projects.

Comment: Re “It seems even if we allocate a certain amount of memory to a pointer, we still can't prevent segfault” and “Sometimes, the compiler may throw an error but sometimes may not”: Segmentation faults and errors are not random. If you handle memory correctly, they do not occur. You need to get your thinking about how memory is allocated and freed straight—it is **your** job to write code that precisely allocates each piece of memory you want and that frees each piece of memory you no longer want.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah. I ended up using just pointers to structures instead of an array of pointers (as shown in the **Definition:** part of the ticked answer), cuz the guy who gave the answer to my previous question said there was no need of an array of pointers (I'm convinced). The definitions of structures used in this question are exactly as shwon in **Definition** in the answer to my previous question — structA has a pointer (that is allocated some amount of memory) to structB as one of its properties (could have more props); each structB has a pointer (allocated some memory) to structC.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Your second response is helpful. When a pointer to structures is malloc'ed, is it then considered initialized? I think yes. Though, we don't know what address it points to. But say if there's a `char* str` in a struct, after allocating some memory to `str`, it also points to an address that we don't know. So, is this string considered initialized simply after malloc'ing? Or we still need to write `str = ''` after malloc'ing, as the string's initialization?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Got your third and fourth points. To clarify your third point, do you mean we usally use `realloc()` to deal with dynamic memory allocation rather than a fixed `MAX_NUM`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196274/discussion-between-spitty-dog-and-eric-postpischil).